# css animation when DOM item loaded and closed

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, animation, dom

Hi i'm using the css animation property to make the element width grow gradually and it work fine when the item loaded to the DOM

the code i'm using:

```
 @keyframes widthSize {
      0% { width: 0; }
      20% { width: 40px; }
      40% { width: 80px; }
      60% { width: 120px; }
      80% { width: 160px; }
      100% { width: 200px; }
 }

.item-popup-list {
animation: widthSize 200ms ease 0s 1;
}
```

the problem is that i want make it shrink gradually when the element removed from the DOM,
can i do it with only CSS, or i must use jQuery (my code is javascript reactJS)

Comment: when and how you are removing element from DOM.

Comment: Please add your entire component instead of just css.

Answer (score 1):

When the element is removed from the DOM, you can't show the animation. All you can do is by toggling the class using javascript/jQuery